# unramified morphism projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

According to J. S. Milne, Étale cohomology:

A morphism $f: Y \longrightarrow X$ that is locally of finite-type is said to be unramified at $y \in Y$ if $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}/\mathfrak{m}_{x}\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ is finite separable field extension of $k(x)$, where $x=f(y)$.

My question is this: Based on the definition above, if I have a finite morphism $f: Y \longrightarrow X$ of projective varieties, I could say directly that:

"A finite morphism $f: Y \longrightarrow X$ of projective varieties is said to be unramified at $y \in Y$ if $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}/\mathfrak{m}_{x}\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ is finite separable field extension of $k(x)$, where $x=f(y)$" Or I need to add hypotheses about Y and X, be like normal varieties, for example?

Comment: As finite implies locally of finite type, your statement is correct. I have no idea why you're doing this, though.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering and still putting the question. I would like to define an unramified morphism of varieties (not schemas), I would like to think about the étale morphisms of varieties to see that they are the same if the morphism is dominant and finite.

Comment: We can define étale morphism for morphisms of varieties (not schemes), using tangent cones for example. But in the morphisms of schemes there is a relationship between unramified morphisms and étale morphisms. This relation remains for the case of morphisms of varieties. To do so, I need the definition of morphism unramified.

Comment: My advice: use schemes. Being a luddite about schemes versus varieties is a really silly thing to be doing if you're really interested in the concept of etaleness.

Comment: @KReiser I think that's a bit rude, and not even a well-taken point. For varieties you can just use the Jacobian criterion of smoothness to define what smooth means. Then, etale just means smooth of relative dimension zero.

Comment: Okay, sure, smooth of relative dimension zero is a great definition for etaleness. But what is one really going to go and do with that definition in the world of varieties? Unless variety means scheme over a field (+ adjectives), what's going to come out of etaleness that you couldn't find through the analytic topology? To me, the cool stuff one finds through the concept of etaleness is the extension of the idea of a "local diffeomorphism" to places where one has no expectation that would work (+ consequences like $\pi_1^{et}$) and the connection with number theoretic stuff, all schemey!

Comment: I understand the point of view of each one of you. And I think it's valid! But I have little experience in algebraic geometry, the schemes part I know nothing about. All I want right now is to study the locus branch of a particular morphism of varieties. What happened is that by chance I saw that for morphisms of schemes the concept of étale is very useful to study the branch locus.

Comment: So I thought about getting the definitions of étale, unramified, smooth, and looking at them from the category of varieties. I am not a professional mathematician, so this has taught me things. I understand the point of view of both. But I imagine it possible to see these definitions (étale, smooth and unramified) in the category of varieties.

Comment: For example, I can define an étale morphism of varieties (projective, quasi-projective) using the notion of tangent cone: let $ f: W \longrightarrow V $ be a regular map of varieties. Then $f$ is said to be étale at $ Q \in W  $ if it induces an isomorphism $C_{f(Q)}(V) \longrightarrow C_{Q}W$ of
tangent cones (as k-algebras).

Comment: This definition for étale morphism is good in the variety category. Now I look for one that is good in the category of varieties for unramified morphisms. What I do not want to do is use the definition of Shafarevich (Basic Algebraic
Geometry 1): "Definition $f$ is unramified over $y \in Y$ if the number of inverse images of $y$ equals the degree of the map. Otherwise, we say that $f$ is ramified at $y$, or that $y$ is a ramification point or a branch point of $f$ ." This I want to prove as a consequence of the morphism being étale.